# Spring MVC shows HTTP status 404

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

This is the error message:-

[image]

This is my project structure:-

[image]

Following is my code:-

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.home.pack;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello";
   }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**HelloWeb-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.home.pack" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I am following this tutorial -> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm but I am not able to get it to work. It seems that I am missing something here and would really appreciate if anybody points that out. Thanks.

Comment: I know nothing about spring mvc but 404 means your url is not correct (resource is not found). Did you check your web.xml and the logic that binds your /hello. How is the HelloWeb servlet related to your HelloController ?

Comment: Just do provide url of particular method as you have just provided method in  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) ... do provide value over here and add it to your URL

Comment: @NiravChhatrola:  But I have already given url at the class level itself.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it.

Comment: @NiravChhatrola There is no need of url on method , if it only one method in the controller class for get request

Comment: @AshwaniTiwari: What could be the problem here, any idea?

Comment: @ParagKadam Go to your server's tab > right click tomcat > add and remove > ensure that SpringTest is added > remove other servers. Restart your server.

Comment: Redeploy the web app

Comment: @JakeMiller : Tried that yet it gives the same error.

Comment: For the present , you can try this : - add the url on the method  @RequestMapping(value = "/helloWeb ", RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {...... and called localhost:8080/SpringTest/hello/helloWeb

Comment: No it again gives the same error.

Comment: Can you specify the name of war you deploy

Comment: Problem seems to be with project structure, configuration or Component scan. Can you share your project on github? That way we can solve this with ease.

Comment: The problem was with tomcat apache. I downloaded and used a different tomcat apache and the problem got resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to show the page "hello"? Spring probably see it as the controller since you did `@RequestMapping("/hello")`... So I guess here you're trying to show the controller as a page, that will surely show 404 error.

Try to change your method as fallow:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
   model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

   return "hello";
}
```

And remove the request mapping on the controller
I guess it would work better...

Or let the request mapping on your controller and change your request mapping of the method for something else and acces it by adding .../hello/yourMethodValue

Comment: No that doesn't help too.

Comment: The problem is , why the above code not run. How to run by other way is another thing

Comment: I see, my mistake.